# how to test sinatra app with session support

Tags: unit-testing, sinatra

the following example in rack-test sounds not works in sinatra 1.1.2

```
get '/url/path', nil, "rack.session" => {:key => "value"}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

try disabling sessions in your test environment. This blog post has a good example: http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra